# ruby date gem utc offset

Tags: ruby, date, utc

I have a unix time string `"1420960690"` in GMT. I could convert it to readable text by using the ruby "date" gem like so:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("1420960690", '%s')
# => #<DateTime: 2015-01-11T07:18:10+00:00 ((2457034j,26290s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The date is displayed in GMT, and I need MST. I don't understand the offset for UTC in the documentation. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html Example or a link in the right direction would be appreciated.

The output im looking for is 2015-01-10T00:18:10+00:00 I'm just not sure how to get to that answer without using another gem.

Comment: `DateTime.strptime("1420960690", '%s').to_time.utc` will work I think.

Comment: `Date` is not a gem.  Since the docs are coming from http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ it is part of the core of the Ruby interpreter.

Comment: What do you mean by "this isn't mountain time" and what is the specific problem?  Do you mean the Date shouldn't be displayed in Mountain Time but it is?  Do you mean the Date should be displayed in Mountain Time but it is not?  What is the expected output and how does it differ from the actual output?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it to English"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the offset for UTC (and usually GMT) is 0. That is what UTC is for.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using.

```
DateTime.strptime("1420960690", '%s').to_time.utc - 25200
=> 2015-01-11 00:18:10 UTC

I got the off set by looking up MST from GMT which was 7 hours, so (7 * 60min) = 420min * 60sec = 25200 total seconds for the offset.
```